# Performance of inline null check vs if-block?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, refactoring

I've been working on refactoring some older code in our repos, and a thought crossed my mind. There are several places where if-statements are used to determine if a certain property or variable contains a value, and if there is no value one is assigned to it. However, These typically take place in long chains, and are somewhat unwieldy.

Is there any significant upside or downside in replacing something like this:

```
if (memo.DateTime == null)
{
    memo.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
}

if (memo.dtoDate == null)
{
    memo.dtoDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
}
```

with this:

```
memo.DateTime = memo.DateTime ?? DateTime.Now;
memo.dtoDate = memo.dtoDate ?? DateTimeOffset.Now;
```

---

Comment: Benchmark it. Time each in a loop (10,000 iterations) and see which is fastest. I'd be surprised if you could find a significant difference.

Comment: [Race your horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: I guess my main question is if there is any reason I SHOULDN'T use the second method. I've never really seen any self assignments like that used in production code, and it just seemed like such an obvious solution to gloss over.

Comment: Fairly sure shorthand is really just that; shorthand. I doubt it gives any differences in the compiled byte code. The second does reassign the variable to itself for no reason, which looks kind of dumb even in that format.

Comment: @Nyerguds: It's possible that the compiler is smart enough to simply remove the self-assignment operations from the resulting bytecode.  Would be an interesting academic exercise to compile both of these and study the resulting IL.

Comment: After a cursory test with a 100,000 iteration loop, it appears the null check performs in nearly half the time.

Comment: If you want to make 'em look more sleek you can always remove the brackets and make them 2-line statements instead of 4.

Comment: Scratch that, I made a mistake in my testing. I was not resetting the stopwatch. It appears that both options result in virtually identical results. so neither option is better, but the null check version results in much cleaner code.

Comment: Btw. almost all the time is spent in getting `DateTime.Now`. Try one way with `DateTime.UtcNow` to see a *huge* performance difference (from about 60 ms to about 2 ms).

Comment: @David For `Nullable` types it doesn't look like the compiler is smart enough to omit self-assignment.  This is also true for reference types.  However, if your variables are purely local it seems like it's at least clever enough to omit the local entirely in certain cases (and just keep the value on the stack).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like syntax sugar:

```
        object test = Console.ReadLine();
        if (test == null)
        {
            test = "default";
        }

        object test2 = Console.ReadLine() ?? "default";
```

in IL Release

```
        IL_0000: call string [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadLine()
        IL_0005: stloc.0
        IL_0006: ldloc.0
        IL_0007: brtrue.s IL_000f

        IL_0009: ldstr "default"
        IL_000e: stloc.0

        IL_000f: call string [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadLine()
        IL_0014: dup
        IL_0015: brtrue.s IL_001d

        IL_0017: pop
        IL_0018: ldstr "default"

        IL_001d: stloc.1
```